# can I change my open ID URL change?

Tags: openid

I wanted to know if I can change my open ID url from say:

> www.abc.com/username

to

> www.pqr.com/username

while the relying party still thinks I am the same user?

or even say:

> www.abc.com/something/username

to

> www.abc.com/somethingelse/username

I intuitively think that this is not possible since if it were, then it is possible for anyone to spoof anyone else's identity.

Also, does Open ID specify which fields the relying party should use to ensure secure determination of the user's identity? For example, I would expect it to club the URL provided with the username/email address sent back by the Open ID server.

Comment: By "change my OpenID URL" do you mean you would login using your old OpenID URL and then edit the one listed on your account?  This does not seem like a security risk since you would have to authenticate to do this.

Comment: I was actually, looking at a generic use case(not specific to stackoverflow where a user can have multiple Open IDs linked to a stackoverflow account).However, it seems that this handling depends entirely on how the relying party is configured.

Comment: Say the relying party uses only the username and email ID returned by the openID server, but doesn't store the original openID URL. Then I could potentially switch providers as long as they send the exact same response. I can see one way to do this is have an open ID sevrer hosted somewhere pointed to by "abc.com". Then some time later, I make "xyz.com" point to it and "abc.com" no longer points to it. Can I just use "xyz.com" as the new URL with a service that accepts OpenID and expect to be loggged in to my old account?

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes that you are trying to login using two different URLs that have redirects to the same OpenID page.

I do not know if it is possible to use two different URLs for the same login because I am not sure what uniquely identifiable information OpenID relays.  Stack Overflow does not currently allow this: different URLs pointing to the same OpenID portal will authenticate differently.

Assuming OpenID sends unique information for each account and not just each URL, it should be possible to swap the URLs without losing any security.

This would not pose a security risk because the same OpenID portal would still perform the authentication, requiring the correct user to login. The OpenID delegation you would use on these pages just redirects to the proper OpenID authentication portal:

```
<link rel="openid.server" href="http://www.myopenid.com/server" /> 
<link rel="openid.delegate" href="http://YOUROPENID.myopenid.com/" />
```

Obviously all security is lost if you identify your account using an OpenID URL for a page that you do not have complete control over.

Comment: "I do not know if it is possible to use two different URLs for the same login because I am not sure what uniquely identifiable information OpenID relays. Stack Overflow does not currently allow this: different URLs pointing to the same OpenID portal will authenticate differently."

Yes, this is what I am talking about. Does the specification mention anything about which URLs the relaying party should store? (if it does)?